# What is the difference between window.parent.location = url and parent.location = url?

Tags: javascript

Are there any difference between using `<button onclick="window.parent.location = url">` and `<button onclick="parent.location = url">`?

Comment: parent goes up a level, but window is the top, so window.top points to itself.

Comment: They should be the same

Comment: @Fallenreaper so to answer my question, using "window.parent.location" == using "parent.location"? In other words both usage would go up a level?

Comment: there's possibly an insignificant (nano-second or less) speed improvement using window.parent.location vs parent.location, because of how javascript works - but it's insignificant :p (read about scope chains and context - but it's really not that interesting)

Comment: Thank you so much!